# What do the following lines in httpd-access.log mean?

Tags: httpd, logging, apache-2.2, freebsd

The lines in question are

```
124.178.138.134 - - [03/Sep/2010:00:05:35 +1000] "\x1e\xaa\xb7P\xcfL\x1eeV*" 200 1617 "-" "-"
203.29.140.81 - - [03/Sep/2010:00:14:58 +1000] "5A\xe8o8*\x1bWxg\x84L\xa2\x04\x13}y\xbc\xd8\xf7" 200 1617 "-" "-"
120.16.62.30 - - [03/Sep/2010:00:21:01 +1000] "\x8b\x9d\x1b\xe4\x8b\x12\x82P\xd83&\x98\\\x89\xc2\x149`9\xac\xd1\xa4!" 200 1617 "-" "-"
86.57.229.206 - - [03/Sep/2010:02:05:53 +1000] "\xaeA\x94\xbd\x95H" 200 1617 "-" "-"
```

I'm assuming the `\x1e` etc that I'm seeing where I might often see `GET / HTTP/1.1` are escaped character codes. `200 1617` matches lines around it, and 1617 is the size of the homepage, to my knowledge. Any thoughts on the matter? This is on an install of apache 2.2 on FreeBSD 8.0 GENERIC.

EDIT: Just got hit with another.

```
121.209.160.33 - - [03/Sep/2010:18:08:33 +1000] "\rz\x85\x0e\xbc\xc2U\xeb/9\x12\x8a-\x8d\x1df\xf8\x11\x8c\xc0\x1b,r" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally those are most likely attacks against IIS servers (this one in particularly might be against the WebDav vulnerability).

If I understand correctly generally there's enough in the beginning to overflow a buffer and the rest is shellcode to open access into the system. Intrusion detection systems like Snort can detect these attempts and reject the submission before reaching the web server.

As for Apache, you're generally going to be safe as long as you be sure you stay updated. If you keep your eye on the access log you'll see plenty of those from bots all over just randomly attempting to infect other servers and further spread.

Comment: There's some interesting information there that's good to know. I'll hold off a tiny while on accepting an answer, but it's nice to know the anatomy of attack.

Comment: Yea, I'm curious as to why they returned 200 statuses so we'll see if someone has a definite answer. I don't have FreeBSD to check against but I surmise it's because the default config routes everything to a default page until a site is actually set up.

Answer (score 0):

Someone tried to fetch documents with those names from your webserver. Its common that worms and script kiddies try lots of various exploits that often look similar to this, trying to exploit bugs in some versions of some web server.
200 is the result code (SUCCESS) and 1617 is the size of the document served.

Comment: ...but 200 means the response was handled and responded too without any problems - which would make me  bit worried. What happens when you try to access the same URLs via a browser?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to go about checking that. Do you mean by typing that on a browser on the machine itself? Won't that still handle a GET request for something nonexistant and not this garbled response?

Comment: You could use `netcat` or `telnet` to connect to port 80 on your webserver and sending "raw" or malformed requests. You don't need to do it on the webserver itself. The "attacks" in your logs are remote, so you may as well be remote yourself. But, as Rob Olmos said in the accepted answer, If you're on an up-to-date and reasonably configured apache httpd you shouldn't have to worry too much. If you have a public web server, there will always be random "probes" and exploit attempts from unknown sources of the outside world.